# How to deserialize json object in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to deserialize the json string to a c# object.

```
string str ="[{ \"foo\" : \"A\" , \"bar\" : \"B\"}, { \"foo\" : \"C\" , \"bar\" : \"D\"}]";

public Class Example
{
  public string foo { get; set; }
  public string bar { get; set; }
}

JavaScriptSerializer Js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Example[] ex = (Example[]) Js.DeserializeObject(str);
```

But I am getting an `InvalidCast Exception`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: str is a C# array, not a Json array, try string str = "[{ \"foo\" : \"A\" , \"bar\" : \"B\"}, { \"foo\" : \"C\" , \"bar\" : \"D\"}]";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<FooBar>>(str);

public class FooBar
{
    public string foo;
    public string bar;
}
```